# How to use @Output in angular 6 to emit an Array of Objects?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-components, angular-forms

I have a Form Having Multiple Input Fields, I want to Output the data filled in the form to be shown in my Page on click of a submit button using @Input and @Output
In my form-template.component.ts-

```js
export class FormTemplateComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

model: any = {};
task: Array<any> = [];
@Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<any>();

onSubmit() {
  this.task.push({Name: this.model.name, Phone: this.model.phone, 
  Email: this.model.email, Password: this.model.password});
  this.valueChange.emit(this.task);
}
```

Now added this in my app.component.html

```
<app-form-output-io (valueChange)="displayArray($event)"></app-form-output-io>
```

Now, defining the displayArray($event) in app.component.ts

```js
outputTableArray: any=[];
displayArray(theArray){
  this.outputTableArray=theArray;
  console.log(theArray);
  console.log('the array');
}
```

So, nothing Comes up!

Comment: `app-form-output-io` is the selector for `FormTemplateComponent` ?

Comment: Do you have an empty message or no message at all ? if no message did you check your submit event ?

Comment: @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<any[]>();

Comment: @Eliseo yes that works, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, you should consider to type your model, and return it with your event.

```js
export interface MyModel {
  name: string,
  phone: string,
  email: string,
  password: string
}

export class FormTemplateComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

model: MyModel = {};
@Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<MyModel>();

onSubmit() {
  this.valueChange.emit(this.model);
}
```

You can also use ReactiveForms and return form model directly.

Comment: Hello  do you have any idea on the changes that we should make if the submit button in the parent component and @Output in the child Component?

Comment: Could you give more details please, I'm not sure to understand. You want to invoke a method inside child component from parent? Is it that?

Comment: Can you be more specific @James

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but with a 2-way-binding array of objects.

```
  @Input()
  services: Service[];

  @Output()
  servicesChange: EventEmitter<Service[]> = new EventEmitter<Service[]>();
```

In the parent component I have a separate dropdown

```
<p-dropdown [options]="services"> </p-dropdown>
```

and a `Create New Service` button that opens my child component,

```
<app-create-service [(services)]="services"></app-create-service>
```

in which I can create a new service. Even If I was emitting the updated array,

```
      this.services.push(newServiceObject);
      this.servicesChange.emit(this.services);
```

my dropdown wasn't updating. **EventEmitter** works with simple data types but not with objects. I think it's because the pointer to the modified list doesn't change, so my solution was to copy my array into another one:

```
      this.services.push(newServiceObject);
      this.servicesChange.emit([...this.services]);
```